# opengl game programme

Tags: iphone, android, windows, opengl-es

i want to develop same game on different platforms like android,webos,iphone(ios)

i heared we can port native code on this platforms.i am using windows.is there any chance for

me develop game in windows and port that into above platforms.

Thanks in advance

Aswan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot just simply port them, OpenGLES has only a subset of OpenGL functionalities, and there's no GLUT in ES.  Besides, each openGL setup code eg:preparing canvas, loading texture can be different from platform to platform.

Answer (score 0):

You can't just copy-paste a Windows OpenGL game to one of those platforms and have it work flawlessly.  There are tools and engines which can help you develop games once and then have it work on multiple platforms (how well they work I can't say, however, I've never used them).  If you check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3528502/need-help-chosing-a-game-engine-for-android) here on SO, there is a good list of choices from the OP, some of which had the aforementioned ability.

Answer (score 0):

Be careful. iPhone uses OpenGL ES which is a subset of Open GL.
A good thought would be to look at [this](http://www.khronos.org/developers/resources/opengles/) before you proceed.

Hope this helps.
Thanks,
Madhup